# How to read file names from a given folder on sharepoint

Tags: python, rest, api, sharepoint

I am writing a tool in python 2.7 that can automate my ETL which will read files in sharepoint in a loop and converts to a dataframe. My ETL is done but I am unable to read file names from the folder on sharepoint that can feed my ETL. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

I have inspected the class member of context.web and I can see get_folder_by_server_relative_url

```
import os

from office365.sharepoint.caml_query import CamlQuery
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import 
AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.file import File
from office365.sharepoint.file_creation_information import 
FileCreationInformation
import inspect


url= "https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/"
username = "blah@xxx.com.au"
password = "blah123!"

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username=username,password=password):
 context = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
 print(inspect.getmembers(context.web))

 lists = context.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url('Shared Documents/ELZ/')
 items = lists.Folders
 context.Load(items)
 context.ExecuteQuery()


 folder = GetListItemFolder(item)
 for item in items:
   print "File name: {0}".format(item.properties["Name"])
```

AttributeError: 'FolderCollection' object has no attribute 'get_folder_by_server_relative_url'

Comment: Did you solve this issue somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Check this example [read_folder_and_files_alt](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/file_operations.py)

```py
lists = context.web.lists.get_by_title('Documents')
qry = CamlQuery.create_all_items_query()
items = list_obj.get_items(qry)
context.load(items)
context.execute_query()
for cur_item in items:
        print("File name: {0}".format(cur_item.properties["Title"]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @waynetech but, I have tried this, I want to get the file lists from folder "shared Documents/ELZ". ELZ is the data loading zone and it can have sub folders and I should be able to navigate to any level. So its hard to tie all kinds of files under titles. All I have is the relative URLS to folders. The URL works absolutely fine when on the browser.

Comment: i don't have a sharepoint account so can't test it but using relative url to folder you can get file list and then use this function to download them

`def download_file(context):
    response = File.open_binary(context, "/Shared Documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx")
    with open("./data/SharePoint User Guide.docx", "wb") as local_file:
        local_file.write(response.content)`

Comment: I could open the individually files, but I needed the list of existing files in a folder. I worked it out. I have posted the right answer. Thanks @waynetech :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below url it's will be helpful to you https://www.mydatahack.com/how-to-get-data-from-sharepoint-with-python/